# How to make text look like password with CSS style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I have the following piece of HTML, generated by the js ([codemirror](https://codemirror.net/)). I'm creating an [overlay mode](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addOverlay), and I'm able to specify the style name for the parsed token.

```
<span class="text">Data Source=myServer;User ID=sa;Password=</span>
<span class="hiddenText">12345</span>
<span class="text">;</span>
```

I thought that once the token is parsed and the style is set, the work should be done, since you can do anything with the CSS, right?

But now I realize that I don't know how to make "12345" string to look like password with CSS styles. It can be replaced with stars (but only visually), hidden behind a plate of any kind, etc. But it should be editable and copy-able.

**IDEA** Is there a special font I can use may be?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but it's probably because you didn't add any code to the question.

Comment: What should I attach? An empty CSS class?

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7734/is-there-a-font-face-in-which-all-glyphs-are-identical?newreg=3a1cc2c644904232a88ac0000f75151a

Comment: The problem is CSS can't replace characters because CSS is not content aware. Will "12345" always be the same? Are users typing this in?

Comment: Take a look https://github.com/kylewelsby/dotsfont

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways - both make real content invisible on top, but absolutely visible in source html code, more - the `::before` and `::after` are always in source  invisible

```
.hiddenText{ font-size: 0}             /* this makes span real content zero size width & height */
.hiddenText::before{ content: '∗∗∗∗∗'; font-size: initial}  

.HiddenText{ color: transparent; }    /* span will be as long as real content + ::before */
.HiddenText::before{ content: '∗∗∗∗∗'; color: initial}
```

```
<span class="hiddenText">I'm so secret</span>
<hr>
<span class="HiddenText">I'm so secret</span>
```

`∗` this is html `&lowast;`
`color` set as you wish
css is case sensitive - correct second span for your page

Choose best for you - other parent or child elements may affect as css is hereditary

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the **type** attribute with css.

You can use the **readOnly** input attribute also the **type="password"** attribute.

You can use this code:

```
<span class="text">Data Source=myServer;User ID=sa;Password=</span>
<input type="password" readOnly="true" class="hiddenText" value="12345">
<span class="text">;</span>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's why I've included first sentence in my post. I can't change the type of the tag to `input`, it has to be `span`, this code is generated. The only thing I have control of is the style.